# How to generate a self signed certificate programmatically in Android and use it for an https server

Tags: android, bouncycastle

I need to create an SSL self signed cert on the fly in an Android app and be able to use it from an https server in the same app. I found this code to create a cert although I'm not sure it is the right kind of cert. And I haven't found much regarding how to add that to the BouncyCastle keystore on my app and then how to use it when creating the HTTPs server. Can someone point me to an example which does this? Thank you.

```
static X509Certificate generateSelfSignedX509Certificate() throws Exception {

        // yesterday
        Date validityBeginDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        // in 2 years
        Date validityEndDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 2 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        // GENERATE THE PUBLIC/PRIVATE RSA KEY PAIR
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());

        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

        // GENERATE THE X509 CERTIFICATE
        X509V3CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
        X500Principal dnName = new X500Principal("CN=John Doe");

        certGen.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        certGen.setSubjectDN(dnName);
        certGen.setIssuerDN(dnName); // use the same
        certGen.setNotBefore(validityBeginDate);
        certGen.setNotAfter(validityEndDate);
        certGen.setPublicKey(keyPair.getPublic());
        certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");

        X509Certificate cert = certGen.generate(keyPair.getPrivate(), "BC");

        // DUMP CERTIFICATE AND KEY PAIR

        return cert;
        //  System.out.println(cert);


    }
```

Comment: What HTTPS server do you want to use?

Comment: I'm probably going to take an existing simple java http server that works in Android and add ssl to it.

Comment: you want to hit HTTPS webservices?

Comment: No, I just want an https server running on Android. I'm not trying to access an https server, I want to be the server.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, sorry, gave up on that.

Comment: @SabaatAhmad The solution is below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution works for generating a self signed certificate using Spongy Castle (Bouncy Castle) on Android. I've tested the code with Android 10 (Q) and Android Pie.

This code is a modified version of Netty's ***io.netty.handler.ssl.util.SelfSignedCertificate***. The original version requires Bouncy Castle; which does not seem to be present by default on Android 10 resulting in a **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider**. Hence, I had to copy over the code and modify it to get it working with Spongy Castle.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.58.0.0'
}
```

**SelfSignedCertificate.java**

```java
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

import org.spongycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.spongycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.spongycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.spongycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.spongycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.spongycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.spongycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;

public final class SelfSignedCertificate {

    private static final String TAG = SelfSignedCertificate.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Current time minus 1 year, just in case software clock goes back due to time synchronization
     */
    private static final Date DEFAULT_NOT_BEFORE = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000L * 365);

    /**
     * The maximum possible value in X.509 specification: 9999-12-31 23:59:59
     */
    private static final Date DEFAULT_NOT_AFTER = new Date(253402300799000L);

    /**
     * FIPS 140-2 encryption requires the key length to be 2048 bits or greater.
     * Let's use that as a sane default but allow the default to be set dynamically
     * for those that need more stringent security requirements.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_KEY_LENGTH_BITS = 2048;

    /**
     * FQDN to use if none is specified.
     */
    private static final String DEFAULT_FQDN = "example.com";

    /**
     * 7-bit ASCII, as known as ISO646-US or the Basic Latin block of the
     * Unicode character set
     */
    private static final Charset US_ASCII = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

    private static final Provider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();

    private final File certificate;
    private final File privateKey;
    private final X509Certificate cert;
    private final PrivateKey key;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     */
    public SelfSignedCertificate() throws CertificateException {
        this(DEFAULT_NOT_BEFORE, DEFAULT_NOT_AFTER);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     *
     * @param notBefore Certificate is not valid before this time
     * @param notAfter  Certificate is not valid after this time
     */
    public SelfSignedCertificate(Date notBefore, Date notAfter) throws CertificateException {
        this("example.com", notBefore, notAfter);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     *
     * @param fqdn a fully qualified domain name
     */
    public SelfSignedCertificate(String fqdn) throws CertificateException {
        this(fqdn, DEFAULT_NOT_BEFORE, DEFAULT_NOT_AFTER);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     *
     * @param fqdn      a fully qualified domain name
     * @param notBefore Certificate is not valid before this time
     * @param notAfter  Certificate is not valid after this time
     */
    public SelfSignedCertificate(String fqdn, Date notBefore, Date notAfter) throws CertificateException {
        // Bypass entropy collection by using insecure random generator.
        // We just want to generate it without any delay because it's for testing purposes only.
        this(fqdn, new SecureRandom(), DEFAULT_KEY_LENGTH_BITS, notBefore, notAfter);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     *
     * @param fqdn   a fully qualified domain name
     * @param random the {@link java.security.SecureRandom} to use
     * @param bits   the number of bits of the generated private key
     */
    public SelfSignedCertificate(String fqdn, SecureRandom random, int bits) throws CertificateException {
        this(fqdn, random, bits, DEFAULT_NOT_BEFORE, DEFAULT_NOT_AFTER);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     *
     * @param fqdn      a fully qualified domain name
     * @param random    the {@link java.security.SecureRandom} to use
     * @param bits      the number of bits of the generated private key
     * @param notBefore Certificate is not valid before this time
     * @param notAfter  Certificate is not valid after this time
     */
    public SelfSignedCertificate(String fqdn, SecureRandom random, int bits, Date notBefore, Date notAfter)
        throws CertificateException {
        // Generate an RSA key pair.
        final KeyPair keypair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyGen.initialize(bits, random);
            keypair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // Should not reach here because every Java implementation must have RSA key pair generator.
            throw new Error(e);
        }

        String[] paths;
        try {
            // Try Bouncy Castle if the current JVM didn't have sun.security.x509.
            paths = generateCertificate(fqdn, keypair, random, notBefore, notAfter);
        } catch (Throwable t2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to generate a self-signed X.509 certificate using Bouncy Castle:", t2);
            throw new CertificateException("No provider succeeded to generate a self-signed certificate. See debug log for the root cause.", t2);
        }

        certificate = new File(paths[0]);
        privateKey = new File(paths[1]);
        key = keypair.getPrivate();
        FileInputStream certificateInput = null;
        try {
            certificateInput = new FileInputStream(certificate);
            cert = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(certificateInput);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CertificateEncodingException(e);
        } finally {
            if (certificateInput != null) {
                try {
                    certificateInput.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to close a file: " + certificate, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the generated X.509 certificate file in PEM format.
     */
    public File certificate() {
        return certificate;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the generated RSA private key file in PEM format.
     */
    public File privateKey() {
        return privateKey;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the generated X.509 certificate.
     */
    public X509Certificate cert() {
        return cert;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the generated RSA private key.
     */
    public PrivateKey key() {
        return key;
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the generated X.509 certificate file and RSA private key file.
     */
    public void delete() {
        safeDelete(certificate);
        safeDelete(privateKey);
    }

    private static String[] generateCertificate(String fqdn, KeyPair keypair, SecureRandom random, Date notBefore, Date notAfter)
        throws Exception {
        PrivateKey key = keypair.getPrivate();

        // Prepare the information required for generating an X.509 certificate.
        X500Name owner = new X500Name("CN=" + fqdn);
        X509v3CertificateBuilder builder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(
            owner, new BigInteger(64, random), notBefore, notAfter, owner, keypair.getPublic());

        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSAEncryption").build(key);
        X509CertificateHolder certHolder = builder.build(signer);
        X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(provider).getCertificate(certHolder);
        cert.verify(keypair.getPublic());

        return newSelfSignedCertificate(fqdn, key, cert);
    }

    private static String[] newSelfSignedCertificate(String fqdn, PrivateKey key, X509Certificate cert) throws IOException, CertificateEncodingException {
        String keyText = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" + Base64.encodeToString(key.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT) + "\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
        File keyFile = File.createTempFile("keyutil_" + fqdn + '_', ".key");
        keyFile.deleteOnExit();

        OutputStream keyOut = new FileOutputStream(keyFile);
        try {
            keyOut.write(keyText.getBytes(US_ASCII));
            keyOut.close();
            keyOut = null;
        } finally {
            if (keyOut != null) {
                safeClose(keyFile, keyOut);
                safeDelete(keyFile);
            }
        }

        String certText = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" + Base64.encodeToString(cert.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT) + "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
        File certFile = File.createTempFile("keyutil_" + fqdn + '_', ".crt");
        certFile.deleteOnExit();

        OutputStream certOut = new FileOutputStream(certFile);
        try {
            certOut.write(certText.getBytes(US_ASCII));
            certOut.close();
            certOut = null;
        } finally {
            if (certOut != null) {
                safeClose(certFile, certOut);
                safeDelete(certFile);
                safeDelete(keyFile);
            }
        }

        return new String[]{certFile.getPath(), keyFile.getPath()};
    }

    private static void safeDelete(File certFile) {
        if (!certFile.delete()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to delete a file: " + certFile);
        }
    }

    private static void safeClose(File keyFile, OutputStream keyOut) {
        try {
            keyOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to close a file: " + keyFile, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```java
private SslContext getSslContext() throws CertificateException, SSLException {
    SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    return SslContextBuilder.forServer(ssc.certificate(), ssc.privateKey()).protocols("TLSv1.2").build();
}
```

I pass this **SslContext** to create the **ChannelPipeline** for starting a Netty server with HTTPS support, but you may use the generated certificate any way you like.

Answer (score 1):

To use the certificate from the answer above in Android (100% working code):

```
        try {
                final SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
                final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
                keyStore.load(null, null);
                keyStore.setKeyEntry("key", ssc.key(), null, new X509Certificate[]{ssc.cert()});
                final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
                kmf.init(keyStore, null);
                final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                tmf.init(keyStore);
                final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
                webServer = (SSLServerSocket) context.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(webserverPort);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

And a minimized version to the method (who will write this in one line? )))):

```
       private Pair<X509Certificate, PrivateKey> selfSignedCertificate(String fqdn) {
            final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            final KeyPairGenerator keyGen;
            try {
                keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            keyGen.initialize(2048, random);
            final KeyPair keypair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
            final PrivateKey key = keypair.getPrivate();
            final X509Certificate cert;
            try {
                final X500Name owner = new X500Name("CN=" + fqdn);
                final X509v3CertificateBuilder builder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(owner, new BigInteger(64, random), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000L * 365), new Date(253402300799000L), owner, keypair.getPublic());
                final ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSAEncryption").build(key);
                final X509CertificateHolder certHolder = builder.build(signer);
                cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()).getCertificate(certHolder);
                cert.verify(keypair.getPublic());
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                return null;
            }
            return new Pair(cert, key);
        }
```